# How do you protect a page using a web.config file?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Heey Stackoverflowers

My question is: how do I protect a Page using web.config or Global.asax?

Example:

Direct url `www.Yoururlhere.com/Account/Edit.aspx` is currently accesible from url bar, but that is not what I want.  I have a login page already with database etc working, only it's missing the protection to remove direct access or by Login.

Can you help me?  My second web.config for Folder Account is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <location path="Edit.aspx"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
            <deny users="?" />
       </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 7):

You are writing in the wrong way. It should be like...

```
<configuration>    

 <location path="Account/Edit.aspx">
   <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
        <deny users="?" />
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
 </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Ah ye ofc Sorry :P:) <Location path="" /> should always outside <system.web>

Comment: Between, if answer helpful, don't forget to mark it as Answer.